# Organizing ArcGIS Server File Structure?

Tags: arcgis-server, datastructure

My organization is trying to decide how to organize our file structure for services we put on our ArcGIS Server. As of now we have subfolders within the root so our structure is:

```
http://<servername>/arcgis/rest/services/<subfolder>/<servicename>/MapServer
```

However, after looking around most other organizations we have found have a structure of:

```
http://<servername>/arcgis/rest/services/<servicename>/MapServer
```

Essentially just putting all the services in the root.

I can see reasons for both, and I can't really see an issue with subfolders, but the fact that most organizations put them in the root makes me wonder why?

Comment: It depends on how many ArcGIS Server Projects you have. If just one or two the root is the default.

Comment: @Craig, using sub-folders will also give you better organization between basemap and operation services (e.g. cached or non cached).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is subjective, and really it depend on the content your serving up.

My experience, one of the main reasons for storing services in different folders is more important when administering security with ArcGIS Server.

i.e. A simplistic approach is to have all open services in the root folder, and then services grouped per role in subfolders.  Then it is very easy to lock all of these services down at the folder level as opposed to having to do them one by one.

If you re-phrase your Q to include more information about the types of services you have, your audience your share them with then I can edit this answer to be more specific.

Comment: To add to security, you can also setup firewall rules to allow access to a particular folder.  Have seen this used when exposing just one folder to the outside world.